# Pspice simulation of NE5234 op-amp internal circuit. Currently getting zero voltage gain

Tags: operational-amplifier, integrated-circuit, simulation, pspice

I'm attempting to simulate the NE5234 op-amp via internal circuits. I'm not currently getting any errors, and so the AC sweep simulation does run, but I am getting 0 V on the output nodes. I'd appreciate any insight, or even a direction I should take to try to diagnose the issue.

[Schematics of all stages with Volt Bias display ON.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IdVQL4y2yhX0j1q3hX7nJEBPGIRTTPp1)

[The same schematics from the Analysis and Design of Analog Integrated Circuits text](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1csiONZX78yf70C2QfPtL14cJeF3HSQWm)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are simulating open loop with one input to ground and the other one biased at 2.5V. Guess what... The out is saturated against 5V supply

Comment: Could you elaborate, on how I can go about changing that?

Comment: Just close output to inverting input so to make a voltage follower. This doesn't mean the whole circuit itself is correct, at a glance it looks somewhat different from the one on your textbook

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your Bias_1 and Bias_CM are open.

They need to to come from a current mirror BJT or at least be tied to (appropriate) voltage sources to turn the other parts of the mirrors on.